# isotope Appended item goes under item already there

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append content in isotope, it work, but new content goes under the items already there instead of after them.

Here's my JQuery code :

```
  $('#og-grid').isotope({
    itemSelector : 'li'
  });

  $('#sort-by a').click(function(){
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $('#og-grid').isotope({ filter: selector });
    $('#og-grid').isotope( 'reLayout' );
    return false;
  });

  $('a#plus_projet').click(function(){
    var appendContent = $('.portfolio_projects_hide ul').html();
    $('.portfolio_projects ul').append(appendContent).isotope('appended', appendContent);
    $('#og-grid').isotope( 'reLayout' );
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Isotope is expecting a jQuery collection as the second parameter.

Though the content is updated properly, using a jQuery collection when appending to the container also makes a difference.

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/TBsBV/)</kbd>

try:

```
$('a#plus_projet').click(function(){
    var appendContent  = $('.portfolio_projects_hide ul').html();

    // Use this variable to append
    var $appendContent = $(appendContent);

    $('.portfolio_projects ul').append($appendContent).isotope('appended', $appendContent);

    // Not necessary when appending items...
    $('#og-grid').isotope('reLayout');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your HTML? It will help figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Insert function works better. 

But items are added twice, first under the items already there, and after, well place after current item with isotope style 'class="isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(438px, 1184px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);">'

Why are they added twice ?

Comment: @MaudeLavoie It seems to be necessary to use the jQuery collection when appending to the container rather than just the HTML string.  I've updated the answer and provided a fiddle to show it working with that change.